# How to make the ball act more realisticly in my pong game?

Tags: javascript, game-development, p5.js

I dont seem to make the ball react well..the ball only seems to go up when collides with the box. I'm programming with p5Play.js

https://github.com/simo8el8attar/MyPonggame.git

```js
let box1;
let box2;
let ball;
let gameFloor1;
let gameFloor2;
let gameFloor3;
let gameFloor4;

function setup() {
  new Canvas(1270, 500);
  gameFloor1 = new Sprite(5, 245, 10, 500, 'static');
  gameFloor2 = new Sprite(1265, 245, 10, 500, 'static');
  gameFloor3 = new Sprite(0, 5, 2550, 10, 'static');
  gameFloor4 = new Sprite(0, 495, 2550, 10, 'static');

  box1 = new Sprite(25, 60, 20, 90, 'static');
  box2 = new Sprite(1240, 160, 20, 90, 'static');
  ball = new Sprite(800, 300, 30)
  ball.direction = 187;
  ball.speed = 6;
}

function draw() {
  background('black');
  box1.y = mouse.y
  box2.y = mouse.y

  if (box1.collides(ball)) {
    ball.direction = -400;
    ball.speed = 8;
  }
  if (box2.collides(ball)) {
    ball.direction = 187;
    ball.speed = 8;
  }
  if (gameFloor3.collides(ball)) {
    ball.speed = 8;
  }
  if (gameFloor4.collides(ball)) {
    ball.speed = 8;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/p5@1/lib/p5.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/p5@1/lib/addons/p5.sound.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://p5play.org/v3/planck.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://p5play.org/v3/p5play.js"></script>
```

Comment: Please visit the [help], take the [tour] to see what and [ask]. Do some research.  If you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output using the [\[<>\]](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do) snippet editor.

Comment: "the ball only seems to go up when collides with the box" what does that mean?

Comment: the paddle in the game